How to install touchscreen and other drivers for Microsoft Surface devices running Ubuntu?
Just installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 on Surface Pro 5 but the touch screen doesn't work, is there a fix for this please?
Also screen has a flicker now and again.

This question is similar to: Touch Screen not working on MS Surface Pro 4 after install (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Installing the linux-surface kernel can support the touchscreen better.
Import the keys
wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/master/pkg/keys/surface.asc \
    | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-surface.gpg

Add the repository
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-surface.list

Update repository information
sudo apt update

Install the kernel
sudo apt install linux-image-surface linux-headers-surface libwacom-surface iptsd

Install the secure boot key
sudo apt install linux-surface-secureboot-mok

Reboot.
Afterward, run uname -a, and verify that the kernel name contains the word surface.

I have tried this but have encountered errors on the 'Install the kernel' step. Can you let me know how to resolve this please?

Errors text: E: Unable to locate package linux-image-surface
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-surface
E: Unable to locate package libwacom-surface
E: Unable to locate package iptsd

Please run sudo apt update and try installing the kernel again

This now works, pleased about this thank you. The finger touch does not work every time, however this may be due to the condition of the screen rather than the applied fix.

If it works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on the top left side of the answer. It may also help future users know that it works
